# Convert tick time to Python hh:mm:ss

Tags: python, excel

I used Python to get time values from Excel but it is in float format so I wounder how to convert time value from Excel which is represented in Python as 0.7291782407407408 to standard time string HH:MM:SS it should be 17:30:01

Comment: What are the units of the time represention in the Excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, time is internally represented as float, with 1.0 being 1 day. Zero point is `1899-12-31T00:00:00`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime(1899,12,31, 0, 0, 0) + timedelta(days=excel_value)
print(dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Yep thats it! Thank you